# jQuery animate - expanding the right text content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Hi I am trying to animate or give any slide effect for toggling the class (the actual expanding), as it is a bit simple at the moment

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqxAR/51/) I am working on with your help at the moment, but it is not doing anything and cannot figure it out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".gamewrapper").click(function(){
    $(".game-name", this).toggleClass("black");
    $(this).toggleClass("expand", 1000);
  });
});
```

Any help appreciated please,

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ or http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery UI [`toggleClass`](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) method is a built-in jQuery method override:

> jQuery UI overrides several built-in jQuery methods in order to
>   provide additional functionality. When using these overrides, it’s
>   important to make sure that jQuery UI is loaded. If jQuery UI is not
>   loaded, the methods will still exist, but the expected functionality
>   will not be available, resulting in bugs that may be hard to track
>   down

the method accept an easing parameter as you are doing:

> easing (default: swing) Type: String A string indicating which easing
>   function to use for the transition.

the problem in your fiddle is that **you are not including** the jQuery UI library.

Working animation fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YqxAR/53/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, I cannot use transitions as IE8+ need to be supported as well, but managed to find a way to fix it with the has/add/remove class functions as the toggle one was not smooth on closing the expand

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.toggleClass()` method only takes 1 parameter, the `1000` you've got in there isn't doing anything.

If you want to animate the css changes between having the `expand` class and not, you have to:

1) Use CSS transitions on those properties:

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

2) Use another plugin. jQueryUI has a switchClass plugin that does that.

http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nicholas,

CSS3 Transitions, jQueryUI or you could also animate all individual styles using jQuery.animate.

E.g

```
$('.classname').animate({'width':'100px','height':'100px'},200)
```